# USB keyboard / mouse dropping events

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard, mouse, hardware-failure

I'm using a wired USB keyboard and mouse on my Windows 10 PC.

I've noticed that very occasionally I miss key and mouse events. For example I will be typing something and a character will repeat as though it's being held down even though it isn't. Similarly with my mouse I'll be dragging something and the system will act like I let go of the button even though I haven't!

It seems unlikely that both these devices have stopped working. Perhaps there's some USB / Hardware issue.

What can I do to try and diagnose this issue further?

Comment: To start, you need to describe your hardware - host processor, USB host controller.